# How can I can make a 2D Png image (a portrait) into a 3d rotating model?

Tags: modeling

i've been trying to find a way to actually take a portrait of a friend to make it into a 3D turning object (a bit like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNbGjMlmzhc) and I've been trying to do it on blender and then export it to after effetcs but nothing works.

I would love some help if that's clear to anyone, 
Cheers!

Comment: There are programs that do this, but not blender. The leading program on the market for this is Agisoft-PhotoScan. It costs a fortune, but your free options like 123D Catch are not nearly as good.

Comment: You could use https://inkscape.org/en/ to export an .svg file and import this into Blender.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of to do this is to use the *image as plane* add-on. First go to *File>User preferences (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>) >Addons*, then search for *Import-export: images as planes* under the community supported level.[image]

In *object mode* press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>>*Mesh>Add image plane*, then when your file browser opens, select the image you want to use. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *edit mode*, and model the plane to your liking, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to *object mode* to apply a *solidify* modifier. From there on, just add any finishing touches you want, keyframe, and you're all set.

Comment: I've actually tried that since it was a recurrent answer while googling but it just doesn't export anything, like i said i'm like a first day user of blender haha here's what it looks like http://i.imgur.com/REGy0vg.png

Answer (score 0):

You would need to actually "Model" it. Simple example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cKFR2P5yIo

In AE maybe Bevel/Emboss an image but not what you want.